# No render data passed with props

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, components

I have a problem with data rendering by passing data from one component to another. I correctly display the data from one component to another but then I am not able to pull the data correctly

Root Component

```
<SelectContainer type={3} data={this.props.templates}/>
```

Child Component

```
import React from 'react';
const SelectContainer = ({type, data}) => {
let option = [];

if (type === 1) {
    option.push(<option value="#" key={0}>Grant</option>)              
}else if (type === 2) {
    option.push(<option value="#" key={0}>1</option>);        
    option.push(<option value="#" key={1}>2</option>);
    option.push(<option value="#"key={2}>3</option>);        
}
else if (type === 3) {        
    for (let i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
        // console.log(i);
        option.push(<option key={i+1} value={data.descTemplate}>
            {data.descTemplate}</option>);                 
    }
}
return (
    <select className="selectContainer">
        {option.map((item) => {
            console.log(item)
            return item
        })}
    </select>
);
}

export default SelectContainer;
```

The img show console.log at return ()
[image]

The select element does not render the data that I send for properties of the parent component. The console.log prints me what I show in the image instead of the data

Comment: I am unsure what your problem is, can you elaborate?

Comment: @canaanseaton The select element does not render the data that I send for properties of the parent component. The console.log prints me what I show in the image instead of the data

Comment: any ideas?¿?¿?¿

Comment: It should be `data[i].descTemplate` instead of `data.descTemplate`, isn't it ?

Comment: @FiriceNguyen no, not found the key "data" is the parameters where data is received

Comment: Hmm, then what do you expect? As from the log, it is a react component which is right according to the code.

Comment: @FiriceNguyen Select and option element no rendered with data passed with props. Render {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "option", key: "1", ...

Comment: Maybe it does not render because the `value` and text is empty. You can inspect your DOM to check whether `<option>` tag is existed in the DOM. What is the value of `data.descTemplate` ? Since it is an `Array`, i don't think the `descTemplate` attribute exist.

Comment: i agree with @FiriceNguyen

Comment: @FiriceNguyen Yes, options elements is created on DOM but empty data. The Array I use to insert the <option> elements is option []. Data has an array of objects with the descTemplate key. If I print below the else if (type === 3) I get an array of objects but if I do the console.log when I render the component it appears what is in the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I didn't find anything wrong. It is working fine. Bit modified snippet :

```js
const SelectContainer = ({type, data}) => {
  let option = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     option.push(<option key={i+1} value={i+1}>{data[i].desc}</option>)            
  }

  return (
      <select className="selectContainer">
          {option.map((item) => {
              return item;
          })}
      </select>
  );
}

const templates = [
    {
      desc: 1
    },
    {
      desc: 2
    },
    {
      desc: 3
    }
]
ReactDOM.render(
   <SelectContainer type={3} data={templates}/>,
   document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

I think their is something wrong with your **data.descTemplate**.

Comment: I think the problem is how the date is invoked. I have to use the props for something?

Comment: Now check and try to relate,  I have added props.

Comment: I have observed that by printing item, the props key is undefined whereas if I use case 2 (type === 2) if that puts me correctly values. That could be happening?

Comment: The data is charged async... Could it be that's why?

Comment: I didn't get what you are trying to say in the question "I correctly display the data from one component to another but then I am not able to pull the data correctly" ? What i understood from the question is that you are not able to get the values in the select. Is it? If not, what exact issue you are facing?

Comment: The problem was a mistake with the api as you said. Thank you!The problem